# Calculating Table of Common Factors in Java

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

I'm trying to complete a short personal project which creates a 20x20 table, printing a '#' where two numbers share a common factor above 1 (e.g. 2 and 8 share a common factor of 2, so that should show a hash). If no common factor is found, a '-' sign is printed instead.

Here is my (shortened to the appropriate bit) pseudo-code:
REDACTED

**The problem is that for some reason it prints too many '#' and '-' symbols, and then suddenly half the factors aren't correct.**

What could be causing this? I have tried going through my code several times with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time you get to printing #, you're 3 loops deep. So instead of printing one # for each coordinate, you're printing a # for each match at each coordinate. E.g. (2,8) - matches at `count==2, count==4, count==8`.

There's also the problem with the state variable reset that user1486477 pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

I spotted a few issues in your pseudocode, but not sure if those are causing your problem, you maybe better off printing your real code:

1. State variable is reset inside the inner loop, so even if # is printed for one of the common factors, - will be printed as well as long as the next value of count is not a divisor. Take the reset statement outside or break the loop as soon as you find a divisor
2. You don't seem to use println or "\n", so how are you doing line breaks?

Hope it could help...

Comment: LIne-breaks are done in a different part of the program (I've heavily abbreviated it for the sake for clarity).

With re: to the loop variable, if I took it out the loop, surely it would only print a # once for a factor, but not for any others?

Comment: Take the state =0 statement outside of the inner loop, also in your if statement check if state == 1 otherwise you print # multiple times if you have more than 1 common factor. Alternatively keep your code, but break out of the inner loop immediately after finding 1 factor.